# 414 Request URI too long

Tags: javascript

```
    function makePage(content1){   
    var content =content1;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
        }
        else{
            console.log("hata");
        }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","makePage.php?content="+content ,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

I am getting error 414 because the data is written inside the url. How can I fix this?

Comment: You're sending a POST request - put the content in the body, not the URL

Comment: You're using `POST` so try to put the data you need in the request body and not in the query string (as what you're doing currently).

Answer (score 0):

With POST requests, you put your content into the body of the request.

```js
xmlhttp.open("POST","makePage.php" ,true);
xmlhttp.send(content);
```

Comment: when i do this the data is blank

Comment: Why is this worth an answer? How HTTP methods work (and where to put the payload/content) should be easy to find - especially for the most common `GET` and `POST` -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @KeremKocdemir - perhaps your PHP code is as wrong as your JS code - or did you mean you no longer have a huge URL? which would be correct ... what cotnent-type does the server expect?

Comment: This is my PHP code
<?php
$content = $_GET["content"];
$file = 'test' . ".xml";
file_put_contents($file, $content);
echo $file;
?>

Answer (score -1):

There is a limit to how much the length of the URL can be so sending large data would result in this error. As you are using post request why not send the data in body instead.

Anything you try will end up sending data in body.

Comment: can you help with this?